# How did my edit get accepted and then revoked?

Tags: discussion, support

I don't understand how my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31565261/revisions) got accepted, but then someone else edited it and removed all of my changes?

What was the point in me editing it if that is going to happen?

Comment: It doesn't look like all your changes where removed and it also looks like a bad edit as it reintroduced some bad formatting and typos

Comment: The 'newest' edit? I don't have access to approve edits as of yet. But shouldn't the person who approved picked up on this?

Comment: When you have over 2000 reputation your edits don't need to get reviewed and are applied automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit got approved at the same second that other edit (revision 3) was submitted. The other editor probably didn't see your edit, for example by starting to edit before you submitted yours.

If the third revision would have started from your edit (Accept and Edit), there would be an approval vote for it by Community.